# Is there an HTML DOM equivalent to JqueryUI selectable?

Tags: jquery-ui, dom, drag-and-drop, resizable, jquery-ui-selectable

Since there are HTML DOM attributes to make an element draggable, droppable and resizable, is there something like it for selectable?

I want to remove JQueryUI dependency (and not replace it with another library) since we don't use the widgets anymore, just the convenience methods for widget handling. When I keep selectable, widgets don't respond to the HMTL attribute settings (Jquery UI takes over drag/drop/resize).

Comment: Did you look? https://plainjs.com/javascript/plugins/selectable-158/ is an example. Since both use new elements, I don't think there would be a natural JS method for selectable.

Comment: @Twisty I amended my question to include the fact that I don't want to replace JqueryUI with another library.

Comment: Then it looks like you would have to roll your own.